# How can I create multile checkboxes in a for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, pyqt5

I just started working on a new python project with PyQt5. It is necessary that the program makes as many checkboxes as there are desired. I am trying to use a for loop for it. But I am unable to use the checkboxname because it is overwritten every time I create a new one with the for loop. My question: How can I see which once are selected after the for loop is done?

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from functies import dataOphalen
import os
import json

data = {}
checkLijst = []
alleVrucht = []


def radioAanmaken():
    col = 0
    for i in data:
        rij = 0
        lbl = QLabel(i)
        ui.gridcheck.addWidget(lbl,rij,col)
        rij+=1
        for b in data[i]:
            check = QCheckBox(b)
            ui.gridcheck.addWidget(check,rij,col)
            #save name in variable
            checkLijst.append({"naam":check,"col":col,"rij":rij,"vrucht":i})
            rij+=1
        check = QCheckBox(("Alle "+i))
        ui.gridcheck.addWidget(check,rij,col)
        alleVrucht.append({"naam":check,"vrucht":i})
        col+=1



app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
ui = uic.loadUi("addNew.ui")
data = dataOphalen("percelen.json")
radioAanmaken()

ui.show()
app.exec()
```

EDIT SOLUTION:

```
for i in range(ui.gridcheck.count()):
        checkb = ui.gridcheck.itemAt(i).widget()
        if checkb.isChecked():
            print(checkb.text())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `isChecked()` to query whether or not a checkbox is checked.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, many):
        super().__init__()

        self.layoutH = QHBoxLayout()

        for i in range(many):
            self.checkbox = QCheckBox("chBox-{}".format(i+1))
            self.checkbox.setCheckState(Qt.Unchecked)

            self.layoutH.addWidget(self.checkbox)
            self.layoutH.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.label  = QLabel("selected QCheckBox: ")
        self.button = QPushButton("Query whether or not a checkbox is checked")
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.ButtonClicked)

        layoutV     = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layoutV.addLayout(self.layoutH)
        layoutV.addWidget(self.label)
        layoutV.addWidget(self.button)

    def ButtonClicked(self):
        checked_list = []

        for i in range(self.layoutH.count()):
            chBox = self.layoutH.itemAt(i).widget()
            if chBox.isChecked():
                checked_list.append(chBox.text())
        self.label.setText("selected QCheckBox: " + str(list(checked_list)))  


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window(7)
    window.resize(350, 300)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]